# Object selection possible only in very small area of game object with generated sprite and collider shape

Tags: unity-game-engine, selection, unity3d-editor

I have a square based game object with scale (1, 1, 1) in my 2D game. The game object has a script added as component which in turn adds a much bigger collider (100, 100) as well as a sprite of same size in its Start() method call.

When I want to select the object I have to click on the very center of the object (Possibly the 1 by 1 area defined by scale?). If I instead click somewhere on the sprite nothing is selected. This is very unhandy.

[image]

*How can I get the Unity Editor to select when clicked anywhere on the colliders shape or sprite (increase the click area)?*

Answer (score -1):

You can use `SelectionBaseAttribute`

Creat the following script and add it to the parent object you want to select:

```
[SelectionBase]
public class SelectionBase : MonoBehaviour 
{
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SelectionBaseAttribute.html

Comment: Not sure if this will handle this case. `SelectionBase` is for selecting a certain parent object when clicking on the childs. In OP's case there seems to be only one single object with a larger collider and sprite

Comment: @derHugo 
1) Attach the `SelectionBase` script I posted in this answer to the parent.
2) Add the desired size child game object to the parent, for selection.

This might not be the prettiest solution, but it works.

Comment: as said .. there are no child objects in OP's usecase .. only components attached to the very same object. I see where you are going but there might be reasons why this is not an option (e.g. when using collision detection etc the scripts might need to be on the same object as the colliders)